# How to hide and watch later related videos after playing youtube video

Tags: video, iframe, youtube, embed

I have created Single page website

I have used youtube video as banner for three months back it was working fine without suggested videoes or watch later icons also not displaying. 
But now after playing the youtube video related videos are being displayed.

I have tried answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321539/how-do-i-hide-related-videos-at-the-end-of-a-youtube-playlist-embed-code) but its not working.

**Code:**

```html
 <iframe id="cbgvid" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6BeG78Uy9_I?rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=0&loop=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGqMa.png)

Comment: Which answers have you tried? Your first sentence needs to be split up and it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Sir,  i have tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321539/how-do-i-hide-related-videos-at-the-end-of-a-youtube-playlist-embed-code

Comment: Yes Sir,  i  have edited the question please help me sir

Comment: I have tried using   javascript  function to controls but its not effective

Comment: Please any one help me

Answer (score 1):

As of September 25, 2018 you can't disable related videos from displaying.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018

> The behavior for the rel parameter is changing on or after September
>   25, 2018. The effect of the change is that you will not be able to
>   disable related videos. However, you will have the option of
>   specifying that the related videos shown in the player should be from
>   the same channel as the video that was just played.

Answer (score 0):

Until September 2018, a webmaster could disable related videos on YouTube embeds by simply adding `?rel=0` to the iframe’s src but after that youtube had changed their embed code so that this `rel=0` doesn't work. However, using `rel=0` you cant stop the suggested videos but you can see the suggested videos from your own channel and not from outside your channel.