# How do I prevent YouTube from offering related videos when my video ends in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, video

How do I prevent YouTube from offering related videos when my video ends?  I have posted a link to the youtube video in my WordPress post, and related videos appear in the WordPress post when the video ends. I do not want related videos to appear.

I have tried adding ?rel=0 but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

They disabled this feature https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Revision_History

Take a look at answers to this question how to use API to hide it: [How do I hide related videos at the end of a YouTube playlist embed code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321539/how-do-i-hide-related-videos-at-the-end-of-a-youtube-playlist-embed-code)